# Geocoder error java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server

Tags: geocoding

#### Code:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(map.this,Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(geoLat, geoLng, 1);
```

#### Exception:

> java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there are lots of questions already asked related to this. answer is its a known bug in emulator but this is geniune question if its coming on a device which is my case... :(

Comment: Yeah, this issue get replicated in the device too though GPS is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error shows up when the GPS is not active. Since the emulator doesnt have a GPS hardware, similar exception can be thrown. Cant say for sure unless you post more detail about the problem.

Comment: Yeah, this issue get replicated in the device too though GPS is enabled.

Comment: I am getting this error in device. The test-app that I made goes fine for few minutes.. but then showers this exception like rain !! :(