# Unable to parse response from server - Geocoder

Tags: android

Okay.. I've seen a lot of questions for this : for instance

[Geocoder error java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754817/geocoder-error-java-io-ioexception-unable-to-parse-response-from-server)  and many more..Nothing gives me a reply !!

Can anyone help me ?? My app works fine for few minutes but then showers the IOException rest of the time :

```
      Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
      List<Address> addresses = null;
      try {
     addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
     if (addresses!= null && addresses.size() > 0 ) 

    txtLat.setText(addresses.get(0).toString());

         } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

     e.printStackTrace();

         }
```

My Log is :

```
      07-30 16:24:20.351: W/System.err(5170): java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server
       07-30 16:24:20.351: W/System.err(5170):  at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
        07-30 16:24:20.351: W/System.err(5170):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:46)
        07-30 16:24:20.351: W/System.err(5170):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:227)
        07-30 16:24:20.351: W/System.err(5170):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
```

Comment: addresses.get(0).toString() print it and see what is the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're trying to use LocationClient class.

Try adding this permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked for me. But I dont understand the reason why!! Can you please explain me as to what exactly happened after adding this permission ??

Comment: This permission is needed to write cache on external storage, in order to save traffic bandwidth. I'm glad I could help you :) Good Luck!

Comment: I'm using `LocationManager` and already have the *write* permission! still getting it?

Answer (score 0):

If its due to permission error in application then I suggest below all permission must be added in AndroidManifest.xml file to ensure no app crash due to location services.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Network is required for getFromLocation() function. So make it ensure to add network permissions.

Comment: Yes re !! All this was obviously added .. :P

Comment: This is network problem. The network you are connecting through may have proxy which filters out Geocoder. So try using other network.

Comment: No need to add `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` as `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` encompasses the same permissions.